# Getting a list of public methods from a DLL

Tags: c#, reflection, dll

I need to get a list of public methods out of a DLL.  I've seen several posts about using Reflection and dealing with the LoadExceptions.  This doesn't seem to work in my circumstance.  When I capture the exception and try to use e.Types, I get 1 out of the 3 types within the assembly.  I already know all of the methods, parameters, etc., all I need is to get the list of classes that are listed within an assembly.

Is there any way other than asm.GetTypes?

Comment: GetTypes is the right way to go; you need to specify BindingFlags if you want private/static/nested/etc classes. Share your code and people can help you.

Comment: 1) Can you please post the code that you are using so we may suggest improvements? 2) You may be interested in `GetExportedTypes` instead since you only want public types. 3) Your title to the question indicates you want methods, but your actual question appears to be about types. Please edit to align them.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found it. This combination works to get a list of all classes without having to deal with the dependencies:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(filename); 
Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();
```

This gets me the list of Types, which is really what I was after.  I'm not trying to execute anything, just get a list of all the types.